What is the correct way to mark up a heading and tagline in HTML?
In this section I have two titles "Why Choice Us" and "Best Choicing For Cryptocurency".
What is the correct way to mark up these two lines of text from a semantics and accessibility standpoint? Is it OK to use an h3 and then h2?

<div class="container">
    <h3>Why Choose Us</h3>
    <h2>Best Choosing For Cryptocurrency</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <div class="features">
        <div class="feature">
            <div class="feature-icon">️</div>
            <div>
                <h3>World Digital Money Secure</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
            <div class="feature-icon">%</div>
            <div>
                <h3>More Profits Percentage</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
            <div class="feature-icon"></div>
            <div>
                <h3>10 Years Experience</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>


See also on Webmasters: SEO and HTML semantics of putting H2 above H1 elements?

Note to close voters: This question isn't opinion-based. There is an objectively correct way to write this code according to the HTML spec.

@Sean The spec says what is legal, not what must be done. And an  followed by an  is legal and semantic. Whether you think it is more or less semantic is opinion-based, as semantics are a subjective matter.

@TylerH That's incorrect. An h3 followed by an h2 is valid HTML from a parsing standpoint, but does not conform to the objective usage and semantic guidelines detailed in the spec. A lack of familiarity with that does not make this any more opinion-based.

Headings imply new sections of a document outline. In the design you shared, both lines of text don't function as separate headings semantically. Instead, they function as a heading and tagline (or subheading)—which needs to be marked up in a specific way in HTML.
Don't use h3 + h2 in this context
<!-- don't do this -->
<h3>Why Choose Us</h3>
<h2>Best Choice For Crypto</h2>

Using an h3 followed by an h2 implies that "Why Choose Us" is an empty child section belonging to a previous section, and is unrelated to the next section "Best Choice for Crypto". This doesn't align with the intended document structure where those are a heading and supplemental subheading (or tagline) working together as the title of a singular section.
Without seeing the rest of your markup, it could also be invalid HTML if the heading preceding the h3 is an h1.
Also don't use h2 + h3 in this context
<!-- also don't do this -->
<h2>Why Choose Us</h2>
<h3>Best Choice For Crypto</h3>

Even though using an h2 followed by an h3 is valid HTML, it's also not appropriate in this case. "Best Choice For Crypto" isn't a discrete child section of the section "Why Choose Us". Instead, those two elements work together to act as a single heading to a single section.
Instead, use an hgroup and h2
<!-- do this -->
<hgroup>
  <h2>Why Choose Us</h2>
  <p>Best Choice For Crypto</p>
</hgroup>

An hgroup element—

The <hgroup> element allows the grouping of a heading with any secondary content, such as subheadings, an alternative title, or tagline. Each of these types of content represented as a <p> element within the <hgroup>.

Semantically, even though it is styled larger, "Best Choice for Crypto" is a tagline that supplements the true heading of that section, which is "Why Choose Us". Semantically, this best aligns with the HTML spec. It's also less problematic than the other two options from an accessibility point of view, because it allows the document outline to match the intent of the content and design.

Thanks for your reply. I have anothor question, is it OK to have a heading with font-size smaller than a p element?

After I had searched for the hgroup element, I found that it is being dropped from the HTML5 specification.

@AsmaaMahmoud Yes, it's OK to have a heading with a smaller font size than a paragraph element. Semantics are independent from presentation. That article is from 2013. It's since been added back to the specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

I found this

@AsmaaMahmoud That is also outdated information. You'll notice the link to the Mozilla page they cite no longer includes that guidance. It's true that many screen readers don't ascribe specific semantics to an hgroup, but this is still the appropriate way to mark this content up, and will still provide a better experience to screen reader users than any of the alternatives.

That's just an invalid heading structure.
As a reminder:

You shouldn't skip levels, e.g. <h2> and then <h4>
There shouldn't be headings of lower levels if there isn't first a heading of higher level, e.g. <h3> and then <h2> if there weren't any <h2> before the <h3>.

The second point is exactly your case. You should  use <h2> instead of <h3>.
Given that screen readers and other tools can provide a hierarchic list of headings to the user, creating an incorrect structure can create bug in such lists, preventing the user from correctly reading the page at the end.
